# Nested ForEach activity using ExecutePipeline task in Azure Data Factory V2

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I've got a ForEach activity fetching data from a Lookup Activity but internally I want to include another ForEach within the ForEach. Since nested ForEach is not supported, I'm using an Execute Pipeline task. But I'm facing issue to call the parameters from my first Lookup. Please suggest how do we send data from first loop to second.

Comment: You can make use of pipeline parameters to pass data from one pipeline to another pipeline. Look for example here: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6136/azure-data-factory-pipeline-variables/

Comment: Yes. It worked by passing parameters across the pipelines.

Comment: Hope your issue has been resolved by pipeline parameters. Let me know if facing any issue in the same.